# Celery asynchronous tasks in django project. How it works?

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, django-celery

I need in my django project run long tasks. Desided to use celery with redis as broker. Installed redis runs:

> The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379

Than I install django-celery, configure:

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
BROKER_HOST = "localhost"
BROKER_PORT = 6379 #redis
BROKER_USER = "guest"
BROKER_PASSWORD = "guest"
BROKER_VHOST = "/"
```

and run it:

```
python manage.py celeryd -l DEBUG
[...]
[2011-06-18 10:31:37,913: DEBUG/MainProcess] Starting thread Timer...
[2011-06-18 10:31:37,914: DEBUG/MainProcess] Starting thread Consumer... 
[2011-06-18 10:31:37,914: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@greg... has started.
[2011-06-18 10:31:37,914: DEBUG/MainProcess] Consumer: Re-establishing connection to the broker...
```

my example task look like:

```
from celery.decorators import task
@task()
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

now I try to run it in shell:

```
In [3]: from message.tasks import add
In [4]: r=add.delay(2, 5)
```

it wait very long and render Traceback http://dpaste.com/555939/. What it can be? Maybe I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BROKER_BACKEND` setting is missing. Here is a example config for using Redis:

```py
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'database'

BROKER_BACKEND = 'redis'
BROKER_HOST = 'localhost'
BROKER_PORT = 6379
BROKER_VHOST = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what this is, but I do know that RabbitMQ is the recommended broker for Celery and Django. I have it running and it works like a charm. Why not give that one a go?

Comment: The problem was that I ran shell as:
> python manage.py shell

Comment: Ah, yes, you can only run celery from a file in your Django app indeed, should have noticed that :)